# MacBook Pro will not boot, begins to load then hangs with white screen

Tags: macos, startup, crash

I am unable to get my MacBook Pro to boot. It turns on, and the Apple logo + loading bar appear however after a minute or so of loading it eventually changes to a white/grey screen and just hangs.

The machine is a 15-inch MacBook Pro from early 2011 running OSX 10.10.5.

I have booted in verbose mode and I couldn't spot anything untoward however similar behavior was observed, just in verbose mode.

I can get to a shell with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> but I'm not too familiar with OS X so I'm not sure where to begin looking for hints about the failed boot.

I tried to enter recovery mode by booting and holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and was able to get the screen up where you pick the recovery drive, but I experienced the same failed boot behavior as described above.

Prior to all this the laptop had a bit of an episode where the video went very funny, top half of the screen at the bottom, and the bottom at the top with some horizontal bars of random colors, like colorful TV static... And it flashes a bit like this just before it hangs at boot... leading me to think it might be something video card related but this is my only clue so far...

Can anyone help me as to where to go from here? Such as boot logs found from the command line, or diag commands I can run?

Comment: We need some additional info like what model year your MBP is and what version of OS X you are running.  Additionally, based on the symptoms you described, it might be beneficial to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: You can obtain all of that info in "[About this Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201581)" or if you cannot log in, issue the command `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` once you boot into single user mode

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to do anything when I hold down D... Thanks for the links, we're considering just taking it to the apple store as described in the link from the answer below, and your duplicate question

Comment: Hi @Allan, I have updated my post with the data from `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` command

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue - More about that here:  https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Luckily there's a free MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program. You can [lookup your MacBook](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/ca/en/;jsessionid=1LBTWM8GVyvkfblntZhRV9QZ7XZLyq9g1fWShZkKyM44n11Gnwc4!-1417462048) serial number if it's covered by warranty.

Comment: How did you determine the model year of his MBP to see if his MBP applies?  Also, per the link you provided:  *The program covers affected MacBook Pro models until **December 31, 2016** or four years from its original date of sale, whichever provides longer coverage for you.*

Comment: You are right. It looks like that Apple extended the MacBook Pro Repair program. Sorry! I have edited my previous post. This sounds pretty much like a hardware issue. @danbroooks Talk to a Apple solution partner next to you.