# Early 2011 Macbook Pro display crash

Tags: macbook-pro, display, crash

In the last week I started seeing a serious issue with the display on my Macbook Pro (Early 2011, El Capitan) where the screen has gone "crazy".  I didn't apply any updates just prior to the issue, so I can only assume that something has changed for the worst.  The screen issues manifest themselves in several different ways:

- Interlaced image.
- Totally "Blue" screen (with alternate lines of differing blue)
- Totall black screen (nothing showing)

This one example:

[image]

There have been different triggers for this behavior such as

- Click on an random link in Safari (especially one with images, or google maps) But not all the time as I am posting here on the system in question.
- Plugging in a second monitor

Sometimes (if I am lucky) I can still see a mouse pointer and shutting down safari clears the issue.  At other times I am forced to power off blindly and at those times it can take 2 or 3 hard reboots to clear the issue an get to a working login screen.

I would love this to be a purely software issue that I can fix by reloading El Capitan, but I am afraid the problem will be related to this question

[Macbook pro checkered display, safeboot works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58896/macbook-pro-checkered-display-safeboot-works)

**EDIT**

**Good News Everyone!!**

It turns out that there is a known issue with early 2011 Macbook Pro's displays and that Apple is going to replace the logic board for free.  This is outside of Apple Care.

This program will end sometime in the future (I did see 4 years after date of purchase mentioned on the Apple site), but even if you don't qualify for a fee replacement the cost of replacing the logic board is only in the order of $USD300 - a lot cheaper than a replacement laptop!

**Edit 2**

Just got an email from Apple containing in part:

```
Proposed Resolution: Replace logic board under quality program. 

Repair Estimate
Item Number Description             Price       Amount Due
661-6082    Board, Logic, 2.3 GHz   $ 567.05    $ 0.00  
S1490LL/A   Hardware Repair Labor   $  39.00    $ 0.00  
Total (Tax not included)            $ 606.05    $ 0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of related to [macbook pro refuses to boot recover hangs at white screen and](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175465/macbook-pro-refuses-to-boot-recover-hangs-at-white-screen) question and [MacBook Pro will not boot, begins to load then hangs with white screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/macbook-pro-will-not-boot-begins-to-load-then-hangs-with-white-screen)

Its hardware related. Logic board needs to be replaced

Comment: Sucks to be me .. Just after I upgraded to an SSD to get some more life out of this laptop

Comment: @PeterM yeah, this is really annoying. If your MacBook is covered by the issue, it's a free repair program.

Comment: Now that you mention it I actually may have apple care for it. I need to check my records!

Comment: Damn.  I just looked .. my apple care ran out in 2015.  It really sucks to be me now.

Comment: Verify your MacBook sn: https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

Comment: I didn't really need to do that as I have the exact date I bought the matchbook and apple care and know hoe much I bought and the link confirmed it, but thanks for the link anyway.  The next question is how much of Apple's hardware lockdown can I stomach in the replacement.

Comment: Looks like I am in luck.  See my edit!